# Unbind datepicker focus event

Tags: datepicker

I use next script to focus on input when validation failes (in ASP .NET MVC)

```
$(function () {
     $(".datepicker").datepicker();
     var inp = $('.input-validation-error:first').get(0);

     if (inp) {
         inp.focus();
    }
});
```

But when my input has datepicker it activated and hide error message.
So I need not to show datepicker when I focus on input with this script

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try putting the `datepicker()` call after you give it focus. Example:

```
$(function () {
    var inp = $('.input-validation-error:first').get(0);

    if (inp) {
        inp.focus();
    }
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function () {
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
var inp = $('.input-validation-error:first').get(0);

if (inp) {
    inp.focus();
    inp.unbind().datepicker(); // this is works
}
```

});

Comment: Please provide an explanation why your answer is *the* answer